# twitter API for python with modifying favorites and other features

Tags: python, django, twitter

I want to make a python program which has functionality like all possible twitter operations mainly **creating and deleting favorites** .

There are many packages like tweepy , python-twitter ,TweetPony ,Python Twitter Tools ,twitter-gobject.

Which python package is best among above, with respect to maintance , speed , features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use package here.
The twitter api is quite straight forward, use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library with its [oauth1](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#oauth-1-authentication) support.

You will need to do some small work to get the initial tokens, but after that, its only straight HTTP calls.

Comment: Ok what u said is Ok , but I dont want to reinvent the wheel, so could you please suggest me a package.